# Display Maximum Quantity in WooCommerce Shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display Maximum Quantity on the WooCommerce Shop page (home page) I used a [get_max_purchase_quantity()] but I do not think that is, I need just to display the value.  [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PAH5.jpg)  plz help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` action hook. code goes in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function show_max_quantity_after_price(){
    global $product;
    if( $product->get_max_purchase_quantity() > 0 ){
        echo $product->get_max_purchase_quantity();         
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'show_max_quantity_after_price', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it return -1 , I think it needs an IF statement.

Comment: :(   it did not work. now there is no error but it didn't return any value. i check the cpanel and add a value 3 in some product but it is not display  :(

Comment: Did you set the stock qty?

Comment: Sorry, I did not set any value in stock qty , but it is display the STOK qty not the Maximum Quantity . i need to display the max qty like the image I send it

Comment: How do you set max qty? can you share a screenshot?

Comment: In woocommerce, there is no tab called "Stock Balance" and also there is no field called maximum quantity. so how did you add?

Comment: sorry maybe I asked the question wrong,  "Stock Balance" and "maximum quantity" it is in the Product section in WordPress panel , there I am adding my products

Comment: Right but this section is not defaulted in woocommerce so you added it by code or plugin?

Comment: @Bhautik you are right, it looks like the theme or a plugin are customising the Inventory tab. Something very similar to what was suggested in this [blog post](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-set-minimum-and-maximum-allowable-product-quantities-to-be-added-in-woocommerce-cart/). If that is the case, then to get the maximum quantity of the product, you can do: `wc_get_product_max_limit( $product->get_id())`.

Comment: yes, that is a plugin! I did not know that, thank you, but I still looking to view a message in the shop page for Max Quantity . i will try @Diego Colantoni thank you too